# Magento 2.2.4 - How to add custom attribute below Price on Product View Page?

Tags: layout, magento2.2, product-attribute, phtml

I have this code -

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getAttributeName(), 'attributename') ?>
```

But confused with the path where to paste this code to show custom attribute below price on product page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show custom Attribute on view page, you can edit `...\theme\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

Find the block with name `product.price.final` and after this block add below code:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.custom" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="-">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getCustom</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">custom</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">custom</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="custom"</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

**Note:** `custom` is my attribute code, You can change it with your code

**Edit I**

You can also add `phtml`like:

```
 <referenceContainer name="product.info.price">
     <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="my_custom" template="Magento_Catalog::mycustom.phtml">
    </block>
 </referenceContainer>
```

Create a new mycustom.phtml inside `templates` folder with following code.

```
<?php 
   $product = $block->getProduct(); 
   echo $product->getCustom();
 ?>
```

Hope Above will help.

Comment: Hi @pawan i want to add attribute below Price on Product view Page, i am using ultimo theme and tried to add your code in catalog_product_view.xml layout files but that is not working. Thanks for you help, any other method or file is very helpful for adding custom custom attribute below product price on Product View Page. Regards :)

Comment: What is code of your attribute and type ?

Comment: Hi @pawan it is text area type attribute which is assigned to all products. We have to show offers (including Images) below price in that attribute.

Comment: And what is code ?

Comment: <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getAttributeName(), 'attributename') ?>

Comment: attribute code - "ppoffer"

Comment: Are you using only xml or set phtml and getting attribute ?

Comment: i didn't set anything till now, i have tried, but i dont have "product.price.final" in my theme catalog_product_view.xml. i want to know how to show that below price.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79179/discussion-between-pawan-and-vinay).

Answer (score 1):

Generally magento use this file to show product price.

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\templates\product\price\default.phtml
```

So you need to put your code into this file.

**NOTE** Do not modify core file directly, better way you need to overide this file into your custom extension then put your code into that.

Comment: i have added code in that file but custom attribute is not showing up below price. Nothing is coming up.

Comment: You can some static text, so you get idea the file which are you looking is this. The attribute value do not show that is another things. for that you need to debug that, have get all information of product or not.